# Error! When I tried to install typings and aws-sdk from nuget package manager console

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk, typescript-typings

Kindly find the attached screenshoot. Showing the error when I tried to install typings and aws-sdk.

I don't know what small things I am missing. I have to implement aws-sdk in my typescript project using requireJS. Have done the code but getting undefined at runtime https://github.com/Prashant-Kan/AwsDemo.

[image]

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: Not able to read the return values as shown in the image. Also, nothing happens after i execute this lines. There must be some problem I guess.
Pardon me if I have mislead something. I am new to typescripts.
My Goal is to use aws-sdk in typescript, which I have tried many approaches but fails for each. Let me know if you know something